# 'Path cannot be found' when executing .lnk files from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, lnk

I have created a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to execute a couple of `.lnk` files.

example:

```
start C:\Users\Blaxie\Desktop\vrchatter\PlayspaceMover.lnk
```

When executed it says that the path cannot be found; but I have copied and pasted it directly from the shortcut properties of the `.lnk` file itself.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you modified, the path in your question? because the shortcut properties would already be doublequoted if the path had contained spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me:
start "playspaceMover" /b "C:\Users\Blaxie\Downloads\PlayspaceMover-v0.1.8\PlayspaceMover.exe - Shortcut"

I just used the name of the shortcut instead of writing the shortcut with the ".lnk" at the  end.